# What web software packages are available to setup a drag and drop canvas for a restaurant floor plan?

Tags: jquery, silverlight, flash, html, drag-and-drop

Hi I'm looking for a software package that implements a drag and drop plan of a restaurant's floor plan. Any technology silverlight/html5/flash is acceptable.

Perhaps there is even a tutorial on how to develop a simple example of this.

Essentially I need different shaped tables which can be selected from a shapes panel that can then be dragged onto the canvas and moved around to match the current floor plan of a restaurant.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you found an answer yet? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try Visio. Or you can build something with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your plans in image format you can do it using vtility.net . Also you can do it using planstery.com . vtility is HTML5 based, but planstry uses Autocad formats